# can I fill a listview with a list of my own class?

Tags: android

I want to fill a `ListView` with a `LinkedList<String>` of my own elements.

My class looks like this:

```
public class Foo {
    public String text;
}
```

this is my adapter and the list:

```
String[] fromColumns = {"X"};
int[] toViews = {android.R.id.text1};
mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null,
        fromColumns, toViews, 0);
list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
list.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

and I also have a `LinkedList<Foo> elements;` which I want to display in my list

Now the question: how to solve this?

1. I dont know what to write into the `fromColumns` to match my `text` value
2. I dont know how to bind my `elements` List to the list so it will be displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom Adapter. You could extend `BaseAdapter` or `ArrayAdapter`. `ArrayAdapter` is a   generic class, so it works good for this example.

A possible implementation:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items) {
        super(context, 0, items);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.some_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.textView.setText(getItem(position).getText());
        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
    }
}
```

Now set the adapter like this:

```
CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(context, getList());
listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

Comment: I edited your answer. ArrayAdapter already has a list and a context, so you can (and should) use them. Also, if you use a custom List in your adapter instead of using the ArrayAdapter one, the default implementation of `add` will not work.

Also, I used `View.inflate` so you don't have to instanciate LayoutInflater and the code is clearer

Comment: @santirivera92 Oh you're right. Just copy-pasted some code from an old project without really paying attention. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Custom Adapter for that..

like:

```
public class AdapterCategoryList extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<SetterCategoryNames> categoryNames;
    public AdapterCategoryList( Context context, ArrayList<SetterCategoryNames> categoryNames ){
        this.context    =   context;
        this.categoryNames = categoryNames;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {       
        return categoryNames.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {       
        return categoryNames.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {        
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder holder;
        if ( convertView == null ) {
            convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.listitem_category_list, null);
            holder = new Holder();
            holder.mTxtCategoryImage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCategoryListItem);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }        
        holder.mTxtCategoryImage.setBackgroundResource( categoryNames.get(position).getCategoryImage() );        
        return convertView;
    }

    class Holder {
        TextView mTxtCategoryImage;
    }

}
```